# Adding n amount of characters to ListBox

Tags: c#, visual-studio, textbox, listbox

I have a listbox that i need to populate with a grade and a corresponding number of + 
So for example if a student has 2 A, 1 B and 2 C listbox will look like: A ++ B + C ++

```
grade = ((Student)students_list[j]).AverageNumMark;
if (grade >= 70)
{ numA++; }
else if (grade >= 60)
{ numB++; }
else if (grade >= 50)
{ numC++; }
```

the problem that i'm having is that the amount of grades (+) is saved as a double and unfortunately i can't write "+" * numA.

How do i make it display numA amount of +s?

Also I know I can do it as a textbox, with enabling multilines, but I'm not sure how to display numA +s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to build the string of + signs in a loop.

```
var aPlusses = string.Empty;
for(var i = 0; i < numA; i++)
{
    aPlusses += "+";
}
```

Do that for each grade and concatenate the response into your text box.

Comment: Ah, thank you (: I had a bit of trouble with adding new lines but I fixed it with textBox1.Text += System.Environment.NewLine + "mark B" + bPlusses;

Comment: @user3097683 Don't forget to mark an answer and up-vote it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the overload of the `string` constructor that takes a `char` and an `int`.

From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa4321w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Initializes a new instance of the String class to the value indicated by a specified Unicode character repeated a specified number of times.

E.g:

```
double numA = 2; //this would be better as an int
string s = new string('+', (int)numA);
Console.WriteLine(s); //prints ++
```